# Possible to pass <form post and etc> from other blade, to other?

Tags: php, css, laravel

I have a website, which was abandoned by developer, but Monday is time when I must show to clients.

Well, we have the following, structure, example, client is on profile page, so we split this page into 2 blades.

Page header is one blade (this displays a header of this page)

Page content is second blade (this displays a content of this page)

I'm moving save button from bottom to top, BUT, problem is, that top is in header page, but `<form method post>` is on page content.

Is it possible, to somehow without heavy developing in php, fix this issue?

content page, have all input fields, with checkers and error messages also, it has `<form post>`
header page, is only displaying a header of this page, and I want to add a Save button, here.

This is partly content page code

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('my.settings.profile.save',['type'=>'profile'])}}">
    @csrf
    @include('elements.dropzone-dummy-element')

    <div class="mb-4">
        <div class="">
            <div class="card profile-cover-bg">
                <img class="card-img-top centered-and-cropped" src="{{Auth::user()->cover}}">
                <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <div class="actions-holder d-none">

                        <div class="d-flex">
                        <span class="h-pill h-pill-accent pointer-cursor mr-1 upload-button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{__('Upload cover image')}}">
                             @include('elements.icon',['icon'=>'image','variant'=>'medium'])
                        </span>
                            <span class="h-pill h-pill-accent pointer-cursor" onclick="ProfileSettings.removeUserAsset('cover')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{__('Remove cover image')}}">
                            @include('elements.icon',['icon'=>'close','variant'=>'medium'])
                        </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card avatar-holder">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{Auth::user()->avatar}}">
                <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <div class="actions-holder d-none">
                        <div class="d-flex">
                        <span class="h-pill h-pill-accent pointer-cursor mr-1 upload-button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{__('Upload avatar')}}">
                            @include('elements.icon',['icon'=>'image','variant'=>'medium'])
                        </span>
                            <span class="h-pill h-pill-accent pointer-cursor" onclick="ProfileSettings.removeUserAsset('avatar')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{__('Remove avatar')}}">
                             @include('elements.icon',['icon'=>'close','variant'=>'medium'])
                        </span>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @if(session('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success text-white font-weight-bold mt-2" role="alert">
            {{session('success')}}
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    @endif
    <div class="form-group">
 <label for="username" class="col-sm-2">
            <span class="h6 small bg-white text-muted pt-1 pl-2 pr-2">{{__('Username')}}</span> 
  </label>
        <input class="form-control {{ $errors->has('username') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }} mt-n3" 
        id="username" name="username"
        aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="{{Auth::user()->username}}">
        @if($errors->has('username'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{$errors->first('username')}}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif

       

    </div>
    
    
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name"  class="col-sm-2">
            <span class="h6 small bg-white text-muted pt-1 pl-2 pr-2">{{__('Full name')}}</span> 

        </label>
        <input class="form-control {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }} mt-n3" id="name" name="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="{{Auth::user()->name}}">
        @if($errors->has('name'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{$errors->first('name')}}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
```

as you can see, this is simple form, with inputs.
and here is a header page

```
<div class="">
            
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3 pr-0 settings-menu">
                <div class="settings-menu-wrapper">
                    <div class="d-none d-md-block">
                        
                        @include('elements.settings.settings-header',['type'=>'generic'])
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-block d-md-none mt-3">
                        
                        @include('elements.settings.settings-header',['type'=>'settingTab'])
                    </div>
                    <hr class="mb-0">
                    <div class="d-none d-md-block">
                        @include('elements.settings.settings-menu',['availableSettings' => $availableSettings])
                    </div>
                    <div class="setting-menu-mobile d-block d-md-none mt-3">
                        @include('elements.settings.settings-menu-mobile',['availableSettings' => $availableSettings])
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9 mb-5 mb-lg-0 min-vh-100 border-left border-right settings-content mt-1 mt-md-0 pl-md-0 pr-md-0">
                <div class="ml-3 d-none d-md-flex justify-content-between menufix">
                    <div>
                        <h5 class="text-bold mt-0 mt-md-3 mb-0 {{(Cookie::get('app_theme') == null ? (getSetting('site.default_user_theme') == 'dark' ? '' : 'text-dark-r') : (Cookie::get('app_theme') == 'dark' ? '' : 'text-dark-r'))}}">{{ ucfirst(__($activeSettingsTab))}}</h5>
                        <h6 class="mt-2 text-muted">{{__($currentSettingTab['heading'])}}</h6>
                    </div>

     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block rounded fixknopki" type="submit">{{__('Save')}}</button>

    </div>
```

as you can see, I already added a Save button, to make in on top. But, it wont work, because form is called in different blade

I tried to adjust CSS , and add margin-top and margin-left for my save button, on content page, but, seems like this is incorrect way of fixing my issue ;-)

Comment: You can use JavaScript to achieve desired work. Simple listen to click event of the button and submit form.

Answer (score 0):

If I’m understanding how these two templates are rendered on the final output correctly: the button does not appear between the form tags. Because of this, the button won’t work because it isn’t part of any form.

To fix this, add an `id` to the form and use the `for` attribute on the button.

```
<form id="my-settings-profile-save" method="POST" action="{{route('my.settings.profile.save',['type'=>'profile'])}}">
```

The value of the `for` attribute in the button tag would match the `id` of the form tag.

```
<button for="my-settings-profile-save" class="btn btn-primary btn-block rounded fixknopki" type="submit">{{__('Save')}}</button>
```

This tells the browser which form a button is for. This should make the button submit that form no matter where it is rendered on the final page.

Comment: for is not working, as it is 2 diffenret blades